# OutOfMemoryError Holding lock : Drools using excel rule files

Tags: drools

we implemented Drools having excel files as rules, working fine for low traffic but experiencing     OutOfMemoryErrors in production (> 100 req/sec).

Any suggestion/help is appreciated.

Error stack trace:

```
  Stack 0: start=0x513d000, end=0x5161000, guards=0x5142000 (ok), forbidden=0x5140000
 Thread Stack Trace:
at jniExceptionCheck+7()@0xf7df37a7
at cmgrGenerateCode+260()@0xf7d77aa4
at generate_code2+937()@0xf7e5f7b9
at generate_code+97()@0xf7e5fa31
at get_runnable_codeinfo2+275()@0xf7e5ffe3
at get_runnable_codeinfo+25()@0xf7e60059
at RJNI_jrockit_vm_RNI_generateVirtualCode+185()@0xf7e60129
-- Java stack --
at jrockit/vm/RNI.generateVirtualCode(Ljava/lang/Object;II)I(Native Method)
at com/xxx/www/framework/drools/Rule_Name_10809963762DefaultConsequenceInvoker.setConsequence(Lorg/drools/core/spi/Consequence;)V(Unknown Source)
at org/drools/core/rule/builder/dialect/asm/ConsequenceGenerator.generate(ConsequenceGenerator.java:142)
at com/xxx/www/framework/drools/Rule_Name_10809963762DefaultConsequenceInvoker.evaluate(Lorg/drools/core/spi/KnowledgeHelper;Lorg/drools/core/WorkingMemory;)V(Unknown Source)
^-- Holding lock: com/xxx/www/framework/drools/Rule_Name_10809963762DefaultConsequenceInvoker@0x78d77348[biased lock]
at org/drools/core/common/DefaultAgenda.fireActivation(DefaultAgenda.java:1018)
^-- Holding lock: org/drools/core/common/DefaultAgenda@0x799cb318[biased lock]
at org/drools/core/phreak/RuleExecutor.fire(RuleExecutor.java:128)
at org/drools/core/phreak/RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:70)
^-- Holding lock: org/drools/core/phreak/RuleExecutor@0x5b00b628[biased lock]
at org/drools/core/common/DefaultAgenda.fireNextItem(DefaultAgenda.java:937)
at org/drools/core/common/DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1201)
at org/drools/core/common/AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:958)
at org/drools/core/common/AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:932)
at org/drools/core/impl/StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:256)
at com/xxx/www/framework/drools/impl/MyDroolsRulesEngine.runRules(MyDroolsRulesEngine.java:163)
at com/xxx/www/framework/drools/impl/MyDroolsRulesEngine.processXLS(MyDroolsRulesEngine.java:88)
at com/xxx/www/framework/drools/MyDroolsRuleEngineHelper.processRule(MyDroolsRuleEngineHelper.java:74)
```

Implementation:

```
     public abstract class MyDroolsRulesEngine{

     private KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
     private KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();

    /*calling drools by passing excel rules as inputstream and inputFact*/
    public Object processXLS(InputStream inputStream, Object inputFact) {

    if(inputStream!=null){
        DecisionTableConfiguration dtableconfiguration = getDesisionTableConfiguration();
        kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newInputStreamResource(inputStream), ResourceType.DTABLE, dtableconfiguration);
        runRules(inputFact); /* calling drools to trigger rule execution */
        return inputFact;
    }
    return null;
    }

    private void runRules(Object inputFact){
    try {
    if ( kbuilder.hasErrors() ) {
            System.err.println( kbuilder.getErrors().toString() );
    }

    kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
    knowledgeSession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(); /* new statefullsession for each web session */
    knowledgeSession.insert(inputFact); /* inputFact has only 2-3 variables/values to validate in rule condition */
    knowledgeSession.fireAllRules();
    knowledgeSession.dispose(); /* disposing statefullsession after execution */
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception  :", null, e);
    }
}
```

DecisionTable excel rule

```
   RuleTable Rule Name      
    CONDITION                  CONDITION      ACTION
    input: InputFact        
    var1 >= $1, var1 <= $2    var2            input.setResponse("$param");
     0,5                        test              02
```

Comment: It seems likely that your rules are going into infinite loops (the usual cause of Drools out-of-memory errors) or perhaps they are just inserting too many facts. It's unlikely that anyone will be able to help based on just seeing a stack trace. Show the code if you want help debugging it.

Comment: Might also help if you explain whether that stateful session is being shared between web sessions, or whether each web session is launching it's own stateful session.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for your reply, I edited the question with more details and implementation code. appreciate your help.

Comment: Are your users uploading an Excel spreadsheet on each request? If not, then you're losing out on performance by not creating the knowledge base once for all users and then just running `newSession`/`insert`/`fire`/`dispose` for each user request. I'm pretty sure that creating 100 new knowledge bases, inserting facts and firing rules, every second is unrealistic. I'm surprised you're even reaching that kind of volume.

Comment: Additionally, depending on the scope of your class, running `kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());` for every request is possibly going to cause the knowledge base itself to grow for every request. It looks like you're repeatedly adding the same set of rules, so possibly Drools will ignore the dupes rather than just growing every time. (I'm not sure on this - would have to test)

Comment: @Steve , we have a single excel rule spreadsheet at common location for all requests.Is dispose() method not helping in free the resources and used memory? Thanks for your thoughts on knowledge base initialization.i really appreciate your support.

Comment: `dispose()` helps to ensure that an existing knowledge base clears up references to session resources. However, given that your rules are not changing for each request, your first step should be to ensure that you initialise the `KnowledgeBase` (including adding your spreadsheet rules and any packages to it) on application startup. Each request should then only do `newStatefulKnowledgeSession` -> `insert` -> `fireAllRules` -> `dispose`. Once you have done that, benchmark again and see whether you still have performance issues or memory leaks.

Comment: @Steve Thanks a lot your support for guiding in right direction.